# "TypeError: Object 8080 has no method 'on'" when running cloak on Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am trying to run my app based on cloak on RedHat Openshift. But I can't even run simple code like this:

```
var cloak = require("cloak");
var _ = require("underscore");
var connect = require("connect");

cloak.configure({
    port: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080,
    autoJoinLobby:false,
enter code here`});

cloak.run();
```

I can run it on my local pc easily (ofc without the constant), but on Openshift, I always get this error:

```
    /var/lib/openshift/550eddc0fcf933a5d9000036/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cloak/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:106
  server.on('error', function(err) {
         ^
TypeError: Object 8080 has no method 'on'
    at new Manager (/var/lib/openshift/550eddc0fcf933a5d9000036/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cloak/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:106:10)
    at Object.exports.listen (/var/lib/openshift/550eddc0fcf933a5d9000036/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cloak/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js:78:10)
    at Object.module.exports.cloak.run (/var/lib/openshift/550eddc0fcf933a5d9000036/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cloak/index.js:78:21)
    at Object. (/var/lib/openshift/550eddc0fcf933a5d9000036/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:23:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

I looked into socket.io and the problem is in this:

```
server = require('http').createServer();
```

On local machine, value of server is changed from 8080 to [object Object], so manager.js gets wrong input. While on Openshift, it just does nothing.

Why does it do this to me? :D

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify the ip address also (possible called host)

```
host: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || 127.0.0.1,
```

Comment: This will be a problem, I haven't found how to change ip address. There is only port option in cloak config :/ ( https://github.com/incompl/cloak/wiki/ServerConfiguration )

Comment: but..when I tried it as you suggested, I've got another error - "SyntaxError: Unexpected number"                                                                                          I am not really sure what these things mean.